# RPC Error - valid string HTTPs rpc in Metamask

Tags: rpc, metamask, ganache

In my project, I tried to connect with metamask on Ganache. But I got the error like the following.

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Expected an array with at least one valid string HTTPS url 'rpcUrls', Received:
> http://127.0.0.1:7545/
> code: -32602
> message: "Expected an array with at least one valid string HTTPS url 'rpcUrls', Received...

Please let me know how can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be assuming your code looks like the following:

```js
await ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
  params: [
    {
      chainId: '0x539',
      chainName: 'Gananche',
      rpcUrls: 'http://127.0.0.1:7545/'
    }
  ]
});
```

The `rpcUrls` value has to be an array, but from your error message it looks like you're passing a string. To fix this, make the value an array as follows:

```js
await ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
  params: [
    {
      chainId: '0x539',
      chainName: 'Gananche',
      rpcUrls: ['http://127.0.0.1:7545/'] // Is now an array
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: If this fixed your issue, would you mind accepting this answer? Thanks!

Comment: I have this exact same issue but your assumption is not correct in my case, so I expect it may not be for the OP too.

Answer (score 0):

you can install localtunnel to  tunneling to local HTTPS server

> npm install -g localtunnel

and after use the command line interface to request a tunnel to your local server:

> lt --port 7545

An url will be created (ex: https://wise-mule-dig-195-131-122-13.loca.lt/)
Open the url created and click on the button "Click to continue"

After you can used this new url instead of http://127.0.0.1:7545/

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and I believe that it is because of the unsafe http url, since it allowed me to pass on the same parameters changing http to https.
So possibly localtunnel might work for you as Patrikoko said?

Another possibility that keeps everything local could be:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ssl-proxy
This serves it with a self signed certificate

In the github readme is says you can serve it with your own trusted certificate as well:
https://github.com/cameronhunter/local-ssl-proxy#readme

```
local-ssl-proxy --key localhost-key.pem --cert localhost.pem --source 9001 --target 9000
```